# How to know if it is the Windows console?

Tags: windows, console

Is there any safe way to know whether the actual window is the windows console?

GetConsoleTitle does not works since the title can be changed.

Comment: What is the "windows console"?

Comment: What is "the Windows console"? There can be more than one console window open at the same time (for instance, multiple command prompt windows, or multiple applications that create their own console windows). Can you be more specific about what you're wanting to know?

Comment: I mean about the windows opened by cmd

Comment: A safe way would be to get the command used to start the actual cmd session.

Comment: What's your motivation for this?  A little context may help us.

Comment: To know if the shell is cmd.exe, command.com or whatever other.

Comment: You can read that out of the COMSPEC environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run *CMD* (or any console based programs) from your program via `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecuteEx` functions, you'll get its process ID. Use it with `EnumWindows` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to find its console window.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd");
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                var window = p.MainWindowHandle;
                // Do something 
            }
        }
    }
}
```